# Separate dots and text from numbers in python dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to separate dots and text from numbers in a dataframe.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
Net.Liq.37584957
Haircut48216354
Deficit10631397
             NaN
Haircutperassetclass
Equity31349682
Commodity12461964
FixedIncome663451
Currency3741257
```

Tried this: df.col.str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)([^a-zA-Z]+)', expand=True), but the first row has both dots and text, hence it comes out in this way.

```
             0         1
0          Net         .
1      Haircut  48216354
2      Deficit  10631397
3          NaN       NaN
4          NaN       NaN
5       Equity  31349682
6    Commodity  12461964
7  FixedIncome    663451
8     Currency   3741257
```

How do i solve this?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Try `df['col'].str.extract(r'^(\D*[^\d.])?(?:\.?(\d+))?$', expand=True)`

Comment: The majority of rows in your DataFrame sample contain a **single** sequence of letters and a **single** sequence of digits.
But the first row contains **two** sequences of letters and one sequence of digits, separated with dots.
How should this case be treated? Please provide the expected output for this source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(.*?)(?:\.?(\d+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5FIYJ2/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\.?(\d+))?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\.?` - an optional dot
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

In code,

```
df[['A', 'B']] = df['Col'].str.extract(r'(.*?)(?:\.?(\d+))?$', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                    Col                     A         B
0      Net.Liq.37584957               Net.Liq  37584957
1       Haircut48216354               Haircut  48216354
2       Deficit10631397               Deficit  10631397
3                   NaN                   NaN       NaN
4  Haircutperassetclass  Haircutperassetclass       NaN
5        Equity31349682                Equity  31349682
6     Commodity12461964             Commodity  12461964
7     FixedIncome663451           FixedIncome    663451
8       Currency3741257              Currency   3741257
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need pattern `([a-zA-Z.]+)(\d+)?`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": ['Net.Liq.37584957', 'Haircut48216354', 'Deficit10631397', 'NaN', 'Haircutperassetclass', 'Equity31349682', 'Commodity12461964', 'FixedIncome663451', 'Currency3741257']})
df[['A', "B"]] = df['Col'].str.extract(r"([a-zA-Z.]+)(\d+)?", expand=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                    Col                     A         B
0      Net.Liq.37584957              Net.Liq.  37584957
1       Haircut48216354               Haircut  48216354
2       Deficit10631397               Deficit  10631397
3                   NaN                   NaN       NaN
4  Haircutperassetclass  Haircutperassetclass       NaN
5        Equity31349682                Equity  31349682
6     Commodity12461964             Commodity  12461964
7     FixedIncome663451           FixedIncome    663451
8       Currency3741257              Currency   3741257
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the column of interest in the source DataFrame has name *Txt*, run:

```
df.Txt.str.extract(r'(?P<Letters>[a-z.]*)(?P<Digits>\d*)', flags=re.I)
```

(`import re` required).

The result for your data sample is:

```
                Letters    Digits
0              Net.Liq.  37584957
1               Haircut  48216354
2               Deficit  10631397
3                   NaN       NaN
4  Haircutperassetclass          
5                Equity  31349682
6             Commodity  12461964
7           FixedIncome    663451
8              Currency   3741257
```

Note: The first column has name *Letters*, but you wrote that you want to separate:

- **dots and text** (actually *letters*),
- from **digits**,

so this column contains actually letters **and dots**.